# Backdated ten year recipisse in France

Tags: visa, resident-permit, france

I just received a recipisse here in France based on an application "AES VIE PRIVÉE ET FAMILIALE parent(s) d’enfants scolarisés".

The recipisse date of validity is "VALABLE DU 22/04/2013 AU 21/04/2023". So it expires early next year but has been valid since 2013. I was not in the country in 2013. I have an entry visa from 2016.

Does this mean I have been issued a 10-year visa? If not, what does it mean?

Comment: It’s a receipt proving the submission of a visa application https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F15763

Comment: When did you apply for the visa ? Was there not a receipt given to you when you applied ?

Comment: @Traveller the agent told me the application was approved and the next time they call me will be to get my residency card. My question is why the recipisse is backdated.

Comment: @audionuma i applied for this visa so I could work based on the fact that my children have been in school here for at least the required time. I have an entry visa from maybe 2016. I applied for this titre de sejour in maybe may of last year.

Comment: Without being a lawyer, my feeling is that they have suddenly noticed that they have not issued the residency card and so they have issued this _récépissé_ to have you covered. It seems sufficiently odd to require some explanation from the _préfecture_, which might be difficult in some places. But it is not the permit itself, that is for sure.